# Better way to find the angle subtended by OI at the vertex.

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Better way to find the angle subtended by OI at the vertex A.

O is circumcentere and I is incenter of a triangle ABC.

So I did solved this problem by finding the distance OI which is $  \sqrt{ R^2 - 2Rr} $ and then I used cosine rule to find angle subtended .   Which is $ \frac{B-C}{2} $ but that took a lot of work. Is there any other better way??

Comment: Which vertex? $A$?

Comment: @MarcoVergamini  yes.

Comment: $BAO=\pi/2-B, BAI=A/2, A+B+C=\pi, OAI=BAI-BAO$.

Comment: in the formula $OI^2 = R^2 -2Rr $ O is circumcentre, not orthocentre

Comment: @liaombro yes I edited that.

Answer (score 1):

Its either $\frac{A}{2} + B - 90$ or $\frac{A}{2} + C - 90$ depending on the orientation of the bisector of A and the line from A normal to BC.